# Javascript multiple click() events not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, click

I have a web page with **Javascript** where I display a list of download items with a checkbox next to each element and a button that if triggered starts the download of all the selected item. The solution that I implemented works fine in Firefox and Chrome but downloads just a single file in Internet Explorer. It looks like the click() event in the code below is just executed once for IE, then it gets out from the loop and stops to execute the function:

```
var links = [];
//populate links with a collection of URLs
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('download', null);
link.style.display = 'none';

document.body.appendChild(link);

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    link.setAttribute('href', links[i]);
    link.click();
}
```

How can I prevent that? Thanks

Comment: Why are you manually adding/updating the dom if you're using AngularJS? That defeats the purpose (and will have some weird side-effects)

Comment: To learn more about AngularJS, there are some great egghead.io videos. Also codeschool has some good free interactive courses, a lot of them are free. I find those to be a fun way to learn the concept and benefits of AngularJS

Comment: @Jamiec it was to give a but more context to the question but I just realized it was redundant. The question can simply refer to Javascript (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

As I get it, it clicks through all the links, but executes only the last one as every previous click is overridden by the new one.

It can be solved by using iframe (I'm not sure about how good this is. I usually archive all files in one, but the cases may differ, and it works) ):

```
var links = ["http://link/to/the/file.zip", "http://link/to/the/file2.zip"];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var f = document.createElement("iframe");
    f.style.display="none";
    document.body.appendChild(f);
    f.src = links[i];
}
```

Comment: Since it's been downvoted, could you please explain why? I'm not offended, I just want to know what's wrong with this approach.

Comment: sorry mate I wanted to upvote but I made a mistake. Make an edit and I will give you my vote